# Error in function 'fwd_prop_enc' :attempt to call global 'forward' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, torch

In Machine Translation Dataset I have successfully pre-trained and trained my model in Lua. Now I move to predict my model.

But I get the error in a Lua file in the function encoder_clones:forward(encoder_input)
Error:  attempt to call global 'forward' (a nil value)

This is that specific function :

```
function fwd_prop_enc(source, source_l, batch_l, train)
local rnn_state_enc = reset_state(init_fwd_enc, batch_l, 0)
--print(rnn_state_enc)
local context = context_proto[{{1, batch_l}, {1, source_l}}]
for t = 1, source_l do
if train then
  encoder_clones[t]:training()
else
  encoder_clones[t]:evaluate()
end
local encoder_input = {source[t], unpack(rnn_state_enc[t-1])}
local out = encoder_clones:forward(encoder_input)
print("yes")
rnn_state_enc[t] = out
context[{{},t}]:copy(out[#out]) -- copy final layer for t'th timestep    (for entire batch)
 end
  return rnn_state_enc, context
end
```

This is how it is called in the main function

```
local rnn_state_enc, context = fwd_prop_enc(source, source_l, 1, false) -- train=false
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means that the function `encoder_clones.forward` doesn't actually exist.

I do not know what framework you are using, but a [quick search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS819US819&ei=W9jJW_6QObHL0PEPvMmZmAM&q=lua%20encoder_clones&oq=lua%20encoder_clones&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9471.9901..10373...0.0..0.120.458.0j4......0....1..gws-wiz.iqv7vkjBHto) revealed that `encoder_clones` is probably an array. Looking at your code, I noticed that your reference to `encoder_clones` is inside a for loop `for t = 1, source_l do`. What happens if you change `encoder_clones:forward` to `encoder_clones[t]:forward`? This will probably solve your problem.

If this does not solve your problem, can you tell us what framework you are using? Is it OpenNMT? We can't help you much further unless we know what `encoder_clones` is and where it came from.